POST Requests Fail with "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch" on Tab Switch
I am sending a great amount of events in batches of 20 events to an analytics tables in BigQuery. Initially, I used sendBeacon but switched to using regular POST requests. Below is the class I use to handle sending events:
import { createControllablePromise, delay } from '../utils/generalUtils';

class EventReporterWorker {
  #requestQueue = Promise.resolve();
  #activeRequest;
  #isPageVisible = true;

  #handleSendEvents = async eventsPayload => {
    if (this.#isPageVisible) {
      await this.#activeRequest;
    }

    const currentRequestPromise = createControllablePromise();
    const cancelTimeout = setTimeout(() => currentRequestPromise.resolve(), 30000);
    currentRequestPromise.finally(() => clearTimeout(cancelTimeout));

    this.#activeRequest = currentRequestPromise;

    const requestPromise = fetch('*MY_URL*, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        accept: '*/*',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: eventsPayload,
      keepalive: true,
      mode: 'no-cors', // Matches sendBeacon's behavior
    });

    requestPromise.finally(() => {
      currentRequestPromise.resolve();
    });

    if (this.#isPageVisible) {
      try {
        await delay(300);
        await requestPromise;
      } catch (e) { }
    }
  };

  sendEvents = async eventsPayload => {
    const newRequestsQueue = this.#requestQueue.then(() => this.#handleSendEvents(eventsPayload));
    this.#requestQueue = newRequestsQueue;
    return newRequestsQueue;
  };

  setPageVisible = isPageVisible => {
    this.#isPageVisible = isPageVisible;
    if (!isPageVisible) {
      this.#activeRequest.resolve();
    }
  };
}

export const eventReporterWorker = new EventReporterWorker();

I am using promises because I receive events from multiple places and want them to be executed sequentially. The only time I want all the events to be sent immediately is when I switch tabs.
However, when switching tabs, some of the POST calls fail and stuck on Pending status.
The error message is:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Events before and after this failure succeed, as shown in the image.
Has anyone encountered this issue or have any ideas on how to fix it?
I’ve tried sending events in batches, added delays, checked the server (the issue isn't on the server side), and confirmed that the internet connection is fine. The call seems to fail at the browser level.
reference image
